# Vlookup to return a hyperlink to different sheet without losing the link

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vlookup, lookup

sheet 1 and sheet 2,
sheet 1 contain ID and **url with hyperlink**.
sheet 2 using vlookup to get data from sheet 1 with lookup value ID to return url with hyperlink.

problem:
Vlookup works return the value but as Text(only url),
**the Hyperlink is gone**. How to return without losing the hyperlink into sheet 2?

Attachment:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIqee.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, problem source from column HYPERLINK (Formula).

```
=Hyperlink(Link_location;Friendly_name)
```

Don't use Argument "Friendly_name" in formula cause "Link_location" need to be clear without any label on it, after I delete the "Friendly_name" , vlookup on sheet 2 to get data from sheet 1 is working and of course the Link also works.